# Why can't my Python script find a custom defined environment variable?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have a Python 2.7 app that uses Tkinter.  The problem is that I cannot read the environment variables I defined when I use Tkinter.

Was thinking this was a problem I am having with Python/Tkinter app, or how I am defining my environment variable or both.  I have tried defining an environment variable in /etc/environment and /etc/profile folders on a Raspberry Pi 2 as the following

```
EXPORT USR_USR="ccj63078"
```

What is strange is I *can* read $PATH $HOME.

To debug I stripped my app down to this writing the contents to a text file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, Tkinter

top = Tkinter.Tk()
vusr_usr = os.environ.get('USR_USR')
user_envd = open('user_envd.txt','w+')
user_envd.write('v_usr= ' + str(vusr_usr) + '\n')
user_envd.close()
top.mainloop()
```

I am not understanding why I can read PATH or HOME, but not one that I defined?

Comment: What happens when you run your minimal example? Is `vusr_usr` equal to `None`? Also, did you reboot after adding the line `USR_USR="whatever"` to your `/etc/environment` (note: you don't need `export` there)? Also worth checking: what do you get if you run `print os.environ` (e.g. in IDLE)?

Comment: There is no command EXPORT.  It should be export.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I changed the EXPORT to export and tried removing export in the /etc/environment and it is the same each way.

Comment: when I look at the text tile the value it returns is None.   when I print os.environ the environment variables and their correct values are listed as I defined them.  so it seems that they are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several files involved during login process (e.g. `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, ...), not all of them are used in all cases. It depends on the way you log in (can be different if you log in locally or via ssh, from a cron job, ...)

Python's `os.environ` probably does not see the environment variable because it is not part of the current environment. Easy to check (no python involved, just shell) using `env` command or specifically for the case above `env | grep USR_USR`. Execute `export USR_USR="ccj63078"` and run the python script (or run the minimum python script to expose the variable: `python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('USR_USR')"`). It should be able to see the environment variable.

The last thing is to figure out why is the variable definition not read from the file it is defined in. It needs more detailed about the way how you log in. I'd suggest to start with putting it to `~/.bashrc` (assuming you are running bash).

*(edit)*
When launching desktop during boot with autologin:

1. `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are sourced
2. It is handled by `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/75source-profile` (comes with jessie releases)

If `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/75source-profile` is missing just recreate it with

```
[ -f /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile
[ -f "$HOME/.profile" ] && . "$HOME/.profile"
```

and put your environment variable definition into `~/.profile`

From a similar question discussed at http://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=37575

Comment: Thank you.  I added the export of the environment variables to ~/.bashrc and when I run the minimum script at the command line python test.py it now see's the environment variables and can use them in the python app!  However, my app sits on the raspberry pi desktop with an icon that fires off a shell script that executes the python app. When I run it this way, it does not find the environment variables. Is there another location I should define the environment variables in?.

Comment: There are several ways. Probably the easiest is to add the environment variable to `~/.xinitrc` (e.g. `cp  /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc  ~/.xinitrc` and then add `export USR_USR="ccj63078"` just after the initial comment).

Comment: Thank you!  That did it! It works now and the python app can read the environment variable I defined when the python app is executed from a shell script! I learned a lot about environment variables and I appreciate your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, what i thought was working, was working because I had added the export USR_USR="ccj63078" to my shell script that calls the python program and I had forgotten to take that out when testing the xinitrc.  So copying the export  USR_USR="ccj63078"  into ~/.xinitrc did not make it available to my python app when executed from the .sh file. Is there another location I can try?

Comment: Sorry, I am not usually running desktop automatically. So this time I actually tried it.

Comment: @mark This should get you running :

Both `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are sourced when lauching the desktop during boot with autologin. Assuming you have  `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/75source-profile` installed (comes with latest jessie releases)  
  
If it's missing it's easy to re-create, it's contents should be:  

    [ -f /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile
    [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ] && . "$HOME/.profile"
  
and put your environment variable definition into `~/.profile`  
  
Inspired by https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=37575

Comment: I added the recommendation to the answer as the formatting of the comment went really bad. @markp

Comment: I added the file but it still does not see the env var in the python app.

This is the desktop file I have 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=RadLab Training
Comment=RadLab Training
Exec=/home/pi/radlab_train.sh
Icon=/home/pi/ricon.png
Categories=None
Terminal=false

OS release running on a Pi 2 
Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"

Comment: Let me check that what I know about your system so far is correct:  

---- You have autologin enabled and boot directly to desktop.  
---- You have added `75source-profile` and `~/.profile` files as mentioned above.  
---- If you open a terminal and run `env | grep USR` the environment variable does not show up.

Comment: That is correct, USR_USR is not listed.

Comment: Could you run from the terminal `source /etc/X11/Xsession.d/75source-profile` and see if your variable is available then?

Comment: Do I just type this  at the command line prompt?  Or do I put it in my .sh script before the Python app executes?

Comment: just open terminal window and type it there, then you can see if it reports any error and you can also check if you USR_USR variable is set.

Comment: When I enter source /etc/X11/Xsession.d/75source-profile  in terminal window all it says is the message you get about SSH is enabled and default password for the pi user has not been changed...This is a security risk....but nothing about environment variables etc.

Comment: When I do env | grep USR_USR it lists it and its value correctly

Comment: Sounds like 75source-profile is not sourced when auto-launching your desktop. Could you run `ls -la /etc/X11/Xsession.d/` and `cat /etc/X11/Xsession.d/75source-profile`?

Comment: ls -la lists about 12 items and 75source-profile is one of them with Aug 29 date stamp.  

cat shows
[ -f /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile
[ -f "$HOME/.profile" ] && . "$HOME/.profile"

Comment: It seems to me there is something misconfigured as 75source-profile approach should just work. This will take probably weeks as the average speed is couple of commands per day. Would it be an option for you to reinstall fresh raspbian jessie? Or let me know and we'll continue investigating the issue (BTW with `ls -la` I was aiming to check owner/group/permissions, not the date).

Comment: Sure, I will do a fresh install of raspian jessie and try the 75source-profile approach.  Then I will check back here if it will let me.  I am getting a message about our extended conversation is too long and to move it to discussion chat.  However, I have not been on the board long enough to run chat it says.  Also, the permissions from everything in the folder from ls -;la is -rw-r--r-- all owned by root.  Thank you I appreciate your help and will check back later.  Thank you, Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm curious how it'll go after re-install. I'm also new here, the chat sounds like a good approach. Need to figure out how to use it :-) Looking forward to hear from you.